# Pre-Populating Parent Child Form from DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-9

I have tried prepopulating the forms from DB records, not happening for child form, I have use all  conventions for Laravel table, pivot table etc., still nothing. The array display with the dd('$allTariffs') but doesn't show on view file, please help am stuck with

***ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given***

**Edit Component Code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\Products;
use App\Models\Tariffs;
use Livewire\Component;

class AdminEditTariffsComponent extends Component
{

    // public $productId;
    public $tariffId;

    public $allTariffs = [];
    public $rowProducts = [];

    public $tariffName;
    

    public function mount ($tariffId)
    {
        $this->rowProducts = Products::all();
 
        $tariff = Tariffs::where('id', $tariffId)->first();
        $this->tariffName = $tariff->tariff_name;
       
       
        // $allTariffs = $tariff->products()->where('tariffs_id', $tariffId)->get()->toArray();
        $allTariffs = $tariff->products->find($tariffId);
    

        // var_dump($allTariffs) ;
        // dd( $allTariffs); 
        
        foreach ($allTariffs->products as $product)
        {
            ['productId' => $product->pivot->products_id, 'basicCharge' => $product->pivot->basic_charge, 'additionalCharge' => $product->pivot->additional_charge];
        }
     
        

    }

    public function updateStatus()
    {
        $tariff = Tariffs::find($this->tariffId);
        $tariff->tariff_name = $this->tariffName;
        $tariff->created_by = auth()->user()->id;
        $tariff->save();
       
        foreach ($this->allTariffs as $product) {
            $tariff->products()->sync($product['productId'],
                ['basic_charge' => $product['basicCharge'], 
                'additional_charge' => $product['additionalCharge']]);
        }

        session()->flash('message', 'Tariff added successfully!');
        return redirect('/admin/tariffs/');

        
    }

    public function addProduct()
    {
        $this->allTariffs[] = ['productId' => '', 'basicCharge' => '', 'additionalCharge' => ''];
    }

    public function removeProduct($index)
    {
        unset($this->allTariffs[$index]);
        $this->allTariffs = array_values($this->allTariffs);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        $rowProducts = Products::all();
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-edit-tariffs-component',['rowProducts'=>$rowProducts])->layout('layouts.admin.base');
    }
}
```

**Edit View**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <div class="card-header py-3">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Edit Tariff</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form wire:submit.prevent="editTariff">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Tariff Name"
                                    wire:model="tariffName" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h6 class="text-primary">Products, Basic and Weight Charges</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table class="table" id="products_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Product</th>
                                            <th>Basic Charge</th>
                                            <th>Weight Charge</th>
                                            <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($allTariffs as $index => $allTariff)
                                        <tr wire:key="tariff-{{ $value->wireKey }}">
                                            <td>
                                                <select
                                                    wire:model="allTariffs.{{$index}}.productId"
                                                    class="custom-select custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm">
                                                    <option value="">Select Product</option>
                                                    @foreach ($rowProducts as $product)
                                                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                                        {{ $product->product_name }}
                                                    </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text"
                                                    class="form-control custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"
                                                    placeholder="Basic Charge"
                                                    wire:model="allTariffs.{{$index}}.basicCharge" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text"
                                                    class="form-control custom-select-sm form-control form-control-sm"
                                                    placeholder="Weight Charge"
                                                    wire:model="allTariffs.{{$index}}.additionalCharge" required>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="removeProduct({{$index}})" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="addProduct" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr>

                        <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3"> 
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-small btn-primary">Edit
                            Tariff</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

**Model File**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tariffs extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "tariffs";


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Products::class, 'products_tariffs', 
        'products_id', 'tariffs_id')
            ->withPivot('basic_charge', 'additional_charge');

    }

    public function productstariffs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsTariffs::class); 
    }
}
```

I have tried prepopulating the forms from DB records, not happening for child form, I have use all  conventions for Laravel table, pivot table etc., still nothing. The array display with the dd('$allTariffs') but doesn't show on view file, please help am stuck with

***ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given*** .thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `foreach` in your `mount` function, you are creating an array but you aren't assigning it to anywhere. Therefore, `$allTariffs` is empty.

Also, you're casting your variables by default as an `array`. You are setting `$rowProducts` as a `Collection`, however. But then in your render you are also getting the `$rowProducts` again. I'd suggest removing the `= []` and removing the fetching of the `$rowProducts` each render.

```php
public $allTariffs = [];
public $rowProducts;
public $tariffName;

public function mount ($tariffId)
{
    $this->rowProducts = Products::all();
 
    // This assumes the $tarrifId always exists. If this isn't the case, perhaps 
    // wrap the related code in an "if ($tariff instanceof Tariff)"
    $tariff = Tariffs::find($tariffId);
    $this->tariffName = $tariff->tariff_name;

    foreach ($tariff->products as $product) {
        $this->allTariffs[] = ['productId' => $product->id, 'basicCharge' => $product->pivot->basic_charge, 'additionalCharge' => $product->pivot->additional_charge];
    }
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.admin.admin-edit-tariffs-component')->layout('layouts.admin.base');
}
```

Comment: I have effected all corrections, still not working, the  **foreach** is use here -  **['productId' => $product->pivot->products_id, 'basicCharge' => $product->pivot->basic_charge, 'additionalCharge' => $product->pivot->additional_charge];**

Comment: @iDRE I've updated my answer with a code snippet of your `mount` and `render` function. Looking at your HTML, all I can say is that it looks fine to me, besides that I am uncertain what `$value` is supposed to reference.

Comment: thanks for helping out, I have effected the corrections still not working the links for photos are added below, the `$tariff->products` gives access to the pivot table this error keeps coming [link]https://imgur.com/a/W1MBCxk, this is for the new code [link]https://imgur.com/a/ZqKG7f6, this is for the model [link]https://imgur.com/a/Hh6zXF6, thanks for your time and effort

Comment: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iuIEqOcQi6g, this is an example, but I want to pre populate form and update not insert

Comment: So in basic I've solved a different issue that you weren't even aware of because the issue of this question is related to `$allTariffs` not being iterable.  

I've once again changed my answer to accomodate to the situation. Your old code (`$tariff->products->find($tariffId)`) was trying to find a product with the ID of the tariff. If found by chance, it would be a product model, otherwise `null`. A model nor `null` is iterable.

Comment: Good day Boss, sorry I was away a while, I followed you instructions on the code and remodified everything, this worked foreach ($tariff->products as $product) {
        **$this->allTariffs[] = ['productId' => $product->id, 'basicCharge' => $product->basic_charge, 'additionalCharge' => $product->additional_charge];
    }**